# Efficient way of mapping similar inputs to similar outputs

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, mapping, large-data

Is there a efficient way of approaching this particular problem in matlab.

I am trying to map this matrix or possible array BeansRice (see below)

```
Beans={0:1,0:1,0:2,0:2,0:2,0:2,0:1,0:1,0:2,0:2}
[a b c d e f g h i j ] = ndgrid(Beans{:})
BeansRice = [a(:) b(:) c(:) d(:) e(:) f(:) g(:) h(:) i(:) j(:)]
```

into a matrix/array BR (see below)

```
BR=[abc, de, fg, hij];
```

where if columns a, b and c each have values 0 (ties preference), I have preference for c>b>a. If all columns a, b and c each have values 1 (ties no preference), BR(1)=1.  If columns a and b have values 0 and column c has value 2, BR(1)=2. If columns a and b have values 1 and column c has value 2, BR(1)=1.

I have an if function with indexing but I was thinking if it is possible to improve it, using the rank/order of the values in the matrix to break ties. Looking for a more efficient process as this is only a sub of a large problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logical indexing instead of if conditions. For example

```
BR1(a==1 & b==1 & c==1)=1
BR1(a==0 & b==0 & c==2)=2
BR1(a==1 & b==1 & c==2)=1
...
```

then process the other parts, `BR2(d==... & e>...)=##`,  then concatenate to obtain what you need

`BR=[BR1(:) BR2(:) ...]`

etc...